# Bootstrap 4 - Push footer to the bottom of page and fill height with main content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a simple bootstrap layout with a header navbar and a footer. I want the footer to be pushed to the bottom of the page if there is not enough content.

I have this so far...

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.container {
 max-width:100%;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
    <nav style="color:white;" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        Navbar
    </nav>
</header>

<main style="background:grey;color:white;width:100%;" role="main" class="container">
    <p>
        Pin Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sollicitudin aliquam nisl, ut elementum eros volutpat ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce felis urna, cursus vel arcu vitae, egestas ornare nulla. Integer aliquam volutpat justo, vitae pharetra mi luctus ac. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam vel magna a ligula viverra posuere. Integer a augue id nunc hendrerit molestie. Morbi tempor sapien tellus, non dignissim ex dignissim sit amet. Suspendisse sed sodales mauris, et blandit mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam eu posuere elit.
    </p>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

It almost works, but I want the main content to fill the height as well. That way I can vertically center it inside the div.

Cana anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `100vh` here and if you don't want full viewpoint, you can cut navigation bar height from it so no scrollbar appers.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.container {
 max-width:100%;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.mainClass {
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
    <nav style="color:white;" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        Navbar
    </nav>
</header>

<main style="background:grey;color:white;width:100%;" role="main" class="container mainClass">
    <p>
        Pin Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sollicitudin aliquam nisl, ut elementum eros volutpat ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce felis urna, cursus vel arcu vitae, egestas ornare nulla. Integer aliquam volutpat justo, vitae pharetra mi luctus ac. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam vel magna a ligula viverra posuere. Integer a augue id nunc hendrerit molestie. Morbi tempor sapien tellus, non dignissim ex dignissim sit amet. Suspendisse sed sodales mauris, et blandit mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam eu posuere elit.
    </p>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Using 100-vh pushes the footer out of the screen.

Comment: Calculating .mainclass is the real solution.  I set min-height of mainClass to {
  height: calc(100vh - <height of header+footer>) in my solution and anything that needs to grow to the minheight gets that class.